# SQL List that continues on a new column after a set number of rows

Tags: t-sql

Im working with a list in SQL, say it gives the result below:

> abcde
>
> abcde
>
> abcde
>
> abcde
>
> abcde
>
> abcde
>
> abcde
>
> abcde
>
> abcde
>
> abcde

what I want is the results ilustrated below

> abcde  abcde abcde
>
> abcde abcde abcde
>
> abcde abcde abcde
>
> abcde abcde abcde
>
> abcde abcde abcde

that is, each time my list hits a fifth row,I want it to continue on a new column

Comment: In pure SQL, this is only possible if you know in advance how many total rows you're dealing with.  Then it's a matter of joining the table to itself once for each resulting column.  This is guaranteed to give you hives.

Comment: My hunch is that you're doing this for presentation purposes; correct?  In that case, it's almost always better to do this kind of formatting in the presentation layer (ASP.NET, Silverlight, PHP, whatever you're using.)  SQL is simply not designed well for formatting output.

Comment: SQL has it's limitations, but this isn't one of them. Solved as described.

Answer (score 2):

Test data:

```
declare @t table (v varchar(10))

insert @t values ('abcde')
insert @t values ('abcde')
insert @t values ('abcde')
insert @t values ('abcde')
insert @t values ('abcde')
insert @t values ('abcde')
insert @t values ('abcde')
insert @t values ('abcde')
insert @t values ('abcde')
insert @t values ('abcde')
insert @t values ('abcde')
```

Expression:

```
;WITH x AS ( select (row_number() over(order by (select 1)) - 1)%5 [rn], v
FROM @t
) 
SELECT REPLACE(STUFF(( 
SELECT ',' + [v] 
FROM x t 
WHERE t.rn = x.rn
for xml path(''), type 
).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''), ',', ' ') [v] FROM x
GROUP BY rn
```

Output:

```
abcde abcde abcde
abcde abcde
abcde abcde
abcde abcde
abcde abcde
```

Comment: Nice!  I may have made a mistake in assuming that the asker wanted their output in separate result columns.  Your solution is very slick if all that is needed is raw text.  Thanks.

Comment: But there is one other possible problem.  The requirement was "each time my list hits a fifth row, I want it to continue on a new column".  This solution does the reverse -- it prints values horizontally, and starts a new *row* after five columns.  Can you spin it?

Comment: Michael Arnes - I answered several questions today, very good solutions. One was even better than the chosen selection, so far I didnt get ANY credit for the hard questions. If you really enjoy my script, you are very welcome to give it a +1. I also encourage you to look at my other answers. Result has been spun.

Comment: +1 for hardcore T-SQL. But I'm not completely sure if the asker is happy now ^^

Comment: Thanks for all replies, and the hardcore T-SQL, Thanks Michael!

Comment: output in separate result columns, that is what I actually required.

Comment: @user473553 for that you need dynamic sql. Put up a question and someone (maybe I) will write it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't really give you the tools to do this in an elegant way as it is a data stuart, and this would be considered a formatting problem.  You should address this on your presentation using looping tools and whatnot.

If you absolutely have to do it in SQL, you can use a cursor, though it will still be rather unpleasant and inelegant.